# How to load different macros for different files

Tags: macros

I have a thesis with a common macros file for all the chapters. I would like to not load this file in my `cover.tex` which is loaded from a `thesis.tex` file as `\input{cover}` but after the cover.

How can I perform this?

Comment: I don't understand the uestion, to be honest. Why not compiling the title page as a pdf of its own and include it in the main document?

Comment: If the "common macros" file is written *not* as a `.sty` (in other words it's written as a plain `.tex` with appropriate use of `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` where needed), then you can use `\input{macros}` *after* `\input{cover}`, no problem.

Comment: @Werner Probably... But it depends what is being lumped together under the heading 'macros'.

Answer (score 1):

This seems unwise:

```
\documentclass{article}
% the filecontents package allows for a self-contained example...
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.sty}
\newcommand\test[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-input.tex}
This macro will fail: \verb|\test{what?}|.
Uncomment to test: % \test{what?}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\input{\jobname-input} % <-- can't use \test here

OK, now load file

\input \jobname.sty
\input{\jobname-input} % <-- could use \test here

This macro won't fail: \test{when?}

\end{document}
```